# assign each number to variable in each iteration

Tags: python

I have matrix x with size 500*3 (x=np.random.rand(500,3)) . I want to make a matrix that does this, in each indices of x, add the first indices and second multiply by third for each iteration and save the number as an index of another matrix y.
 This is what I did

```
 y_n=np.zeros((500,1))

for i in x_n:
    for j in y_n:
            y_n[k]=i[0]*i[1]+i[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to iterate `y_n`, just store the values in `y_n` using the current index of `x_n`. To get the current index, you can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for i, x in enumerate(x_n):
    y_n[ind] = x[0]*x[1]+x[2]
```